# Does Ubuntu Core support real-time?

Tags: ubuntu-core, realtime, embedded-system

Does Ubuntu Core's kernel support (hard) real-time?

If not, is it using a standard kernel, which can be patched with the [CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT set](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT_Patch)?

Comment: You can always check alternative kernels before trying to compile one yourself. Please look at `Liquorix` here: https://liquorix.net/#features , one of the features there is "Hard Kernel Preemption: Most aggressive kernel preemption before requiring real-time patches. Guarantees responsive system under high intensity mixed workload scenarios."